# How to search cross web application in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: search

Any ideas on how to search cross web application in SharePoint 2013? I'm new to search and don't really know how to begin, but it should at least be possible, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

To start off when [setting up search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502597.aspx) it will automatically search all the local sites.
Once search is set up you can add additional [Result Sources](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683115.aspx) which can be any URL. You can also decide how deep you want to search those external applications.

Comment: Hi, I've tried it all by the book and it did not work on my machine but on another it did, so it seems I messed something up in me setup.

Comment: Search does have a lot that can go wrong. If something does it is usually easiest to scrap it and start over. Do as much as you can in powershell scripts and it will make it a lot easier if you need to set it up on more than one server/farm.